# Combobox using repositoryItems like autocomplete mode

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I use `Grid` control for data entry, and one column I made `ComboBox` using repositoryItems . Now I want to know if there is an option that while I type some text into `Combobox` cell to display a drop down list of possible entries. Something like autocomplete options.

Comment: Look at the `AutoComplete` property https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsLookUpEditBase_AutoCompletetopic

Comment: @Sybren, it's a link for WPF.
In WinForms combobox autocomplete is enabled by default. See https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemComboBox_AutoCompletetopic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such option in `RepositoryItemComboBox`. You can find the [`RepositoryItemComboBox.AutoComplete`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemComboBox_AutoCompletetopic) property, but this property does not show the list of possible entries. It shows all entries:
[image: AutoComplete in ComboBox]
You can get the drop down list of possible entries by using [`RepositoryItemLookUpEdit`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEdittopic) class and set [`RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.SearchMode`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEdit_SearchModetopic) property to [`AutoFilter`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsControlsSearchModeEnumtopic) value:
[image: AutoComplete in LookUpEdit]
Also you can find such functionality in [`RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemGridLookUpEdittopic) class:
[image: AutoComplete in GridLookUpEdit]
And in [`RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdittopic) class:
[image: AutoComplete in SearchLookUpEdit]